# Restore default folder/save options windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-libraries

Here was my original problem.

Using an FTP Program, I noticed that every time I downloaded a file it would send it to "User\username\My Documents.
I had changed the "My Documents" Library to "Files" in order to organize and add a little redundancy to my files. In doing so, I now don't have a "My Documents" Library. So when something saves to "My Documents" I have to go all the way to User\Username and open the recreated "My Documents" folder and move the file to the designated spot. 
In hopes of fixing this, I tried a few methods using Shortcuts and link folders, but before I found a solution, something odd started happening which brings me the current problem.

while I was trying to solve the first problem, I made a folder (We'll call it Folder1)
I then deleted that folder because it didn't solve my problem the way I wanted it to.

but now, somehow, that folder appears to be systematically linked to explorer.

A couple of examples:

1: when creating a new Virtual Machine, the default save location is now "/User/username/Files/Folder1" 
2: Playing Age of Empires, the Game Data now auto-saves to "/user/username/Files/Folder1"

This causes a lot of major inconveniences especially since not all installations give you options as to where to store certain files (Like Age of Empires)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: "I tried a few methods using Shortcuts and link folders..."  Ok, undid what you did to start it. if you don't know what you did (then how are we supposed to?) perhaps restore from your most recent backup.  Use System Restore to go back to before you changed whatever it is you changed. to me it sounds like you changed the path of "My Documents" to "/User/username/Files/Folder1", what's shown as the path assigned to My Documents (or whatever you renamed it to) when you look at it's Properties->Location?

Comment: Solved my own problem.

Be a little nicer next time, perhaps.

Comment: The answer was in the question.

Files is the new "My Documents"
So revert that folder to the previous version and then change the filepath. 

Use were less than helpful and rude.

Comment: Perhaps explain exactly what you did, and show some effort in rectifying you own problem next time please.  Also, if you've solved your own problem, why not type it up in an answer to your own question (it's allowed) to help out others who may come along?

Comment: I already planned on it. 
I resolved my problem 6 hour in to posting the question. 
required more time before I could answer it.

and this site is for SUperUsers. You should expect that that I have attempted all the common solutions.
However, I understand that perhaps not everybody that posts on this site does their due-duligence. Now that being said, you could have simply replied, "Before we begin, have you attempted restoring the files or perhaps checking the properties of your files?"

Comment: I would have cheerfully responded with an adequate answer. anyone reading that would have known that the file was being linked to the other file. Kind of a given. If you had read the top, you would have seen that that is the problem since the two files linking Didn't exist

Comment: Please dude, you're reading too much into this.  If you had provided clear information I wouldn't have had to ask.  Sorry you don't appreciate the help I was trying to give, or how I was giving it.  Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the question, can't believe I hadn't thought of it before

Files is the new "My Documents"
So therefore, "My Documents" still exists.

So revert that folder to the previous version and then change the filepath.